# C# How to skip or not skip line conditionally

Tags: c#, linq

below is small code snippet where i am reading a csv file and skip first because because first line has field name. so how could i skip or not skip line based on condition. suppose **country code is US or MX** then first line will not be skipped but if **country code is GB or FR** then first line would be skip. suggest me what to add in my below code as a result first line skip will depend on condition.

```
public List<PhoneData> GetPhoneData(string strFileName)
        {
            return File.ReadLines(strFileName)
                .Skip(1)
                .Where(s => s != "")
                .Select(s => s.Split(new[] { ',' }))
                .Select(a => new PhoneData
                {
                    Call_Start = DateTime.Parse( a[0]),
                    call_duration = TimeSpan.Parse(a[1]),
                    Ring_duration = int.Parse(a[2]),
                    direction = a[4],
                    Is_Internal =Convert.ToInt32( a[8]),
                    continuation = int.Parse( a[10]),
                    party1name = a[13],
                    Caller = a[3],
                    Park_Time = Convert.ToInt32(a[16]),
                    Called_number = a[5]
                })
                .ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which line do you wish to skip conditionally? The first line? Where does the country code come from? Is it different for each line?

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. Do you want to skip the first line because it contains only field names? So there is no condition... You don't determine a country code in your last `Select`. Where should that come from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [ternary expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ty67wk28.aspx) will do it

```
return File.ReadLines(strFileName)
            .Skip(someCondition ? 0 : 1)
```